# How to serialize a list of objects with JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm developing a software to manage my collection of coins. I need to export the content of a list of objects in a JSON file but I encounter this error everytime I want to display the coins that are actually inside the database:

Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: [. Path '', line 1, position 109.

Here's where everything should happen:

```
List<Coin> coins = new List<Coin>();

public bool AddACoin (int ID, String coinName, String coinNation, String coinStatus, int coinYear, int quantity, float value)
{
    var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        coins.Add(new Coin(ID, coinName, coinNation, coinStatus, coinYear, quantity, value));
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, coins.ToList());
    }

    return true;
}
```

The output is stored inside different blocks of square brackets. I've a block for every object inserted. Instead I should have every object inside a unique block of square brackets. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Here's the content of the JSON file

```
[{"ID":0,"coinName":"1 Euro","coinNation":"Ita","coinStatus":"FdC","coinYear":2005,"quantity":1,"value":4.7}][{"ID":0,"coinName":"1 Euro","coinNation":"Ita","coinStatus":"FdC","coinYear":2005,"quantity":1,"value":4.7},{"ID":1,"coinName":"2 Euro","coinNation":"Bel","coinStatus":"FdC","coinYear":2004,"quantity":1,"value":30.0}]
```

As I said, everything should be inside a unique block of square brackets.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON?

Comment: @sellotape here's the JSON

Comment: You don't have a comma between ] and [.... Take a look at https://www.json.org/ to understand the JSON format.

Comment: Actually if I can guess what you're doing, if you're _appending_ a chunk of JSON repeatedly to a file, then that will not work (without help). You will either need to parse out the "blocks" yourself, or - if the expected size and concurrency is compatible - reload the existing JSON into a class, append the new data, then reserialize the whole thing back to the file.

Comment: @sellotape the comma should be between } and {. If I put a comma between ] and [ I receive a "Multiple JSON Root Elements" error (I've tried some JSON validators). The point is that I should have [{object1},{object2},...,{objectN}] but it doesn't happen. Everytime I run the program I have [{object1},{object2}] and then, after another run, again [{object1},{object2},{object3}]. It depends on how many objects I insert inside the list everytime I run the program.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I've just found the solution to my problem and I'm going to share it with you. I've changed some lines and now I have:

```
public bool AddACoin (int ID, String coinName, String coinNation, String coinStatus, int coinYear, int quantity, float value)
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, true))
        {
            string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(json);
            coins.Add(new Coin(ID, coinName, coinNation, coinStatus, coinYear, quantity, value));
            string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(coins);
            streamReader.Close();
            File.WriteAllText(path, newJson);
        }
            return true;
    }
```

If I'm thinking correctly, doing this causes the program to read until it reaches EOF and then, after serializing/deserializing the list, appends the new object. At the moment this seems to works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use NewtonsoftJSON (you can install it via NuGet), clear json file every time you adding new coin, there are coins manager sample for you:

```
public class CoinsManager
{
    public List<Coin> Coins { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public CoinsManager(string filePath)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
        Coins = new List<Coin>();
    }

    public void LoadCoins()
    {
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            //If file exists, but empty, save empty settings to it
            if (new FileInfo(FilePath).Length == 0)
            {
                SaveSettings();
            }
            else
            {
                //Read json from file
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(FilePath))
                {
                    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                    //Convert json to list
                    Coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(json);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Create file
            File.Create(FilePath).Close();

            //Wait for filesystem to create file
            while (!File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            //Save empty settings to file
            SaveSettings();
        }
    }

    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Coins);

        File.WriteAllText(FilePath, json);
    }

    //Can save or update passed coin
    public void SaveCoin(Coin coin)
    {
        //Select old coin
        var oldCoin = Coins.Where(c => c.ID == coin.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        //If there was no old coin, get last existing coin id, or zero if Coins list is empty
        if (oldCoin == null)
        {
            int lastId;
            if (Coins.Count != 0)
                lastId = Coins.Count - 1;
            else
                lastId = 0;

            coin.ID = lastId + 1;
            Coins.Add(coin);
        }
        else
        {
            int index = Coins.IndexOf(oldCoin);
            Coins[index] = coin;
        }
    }

    public void DeleteCoin(Coin coin)
    {
        Coins.RemoveAll(c => c.ID == coin.Id);
    }
}
```

and it's usage:

```
    CoinsManager coinsManager = new CoinsManager("coinsStorage.json");
    coinsManager.LoadCoins();
    coinsManager.SaveCoin(new Coin {
    ...
    });
    coinsManager.SaveSettings();
```

Comment: Well I know there are coins manager but I'd like to develop my own one. It's like a "coding challenge" but mostly it's a good way to learn new things about coding

Comment: Ok, so try to empty file before every coin insertion. Looks like you appending new serialized list to old, and as result, you have many blocks of square brackets

Comment: Using what you suggest, I should create two files. I can put everything I insert everytime I run the program in a temp file. In the other one, I can merge the content of the temp file with the "definitive" one. If there's nothing more quicker, I can try this solution.

Comment: You shouldn't use two files, before inserting a new coin, you need: **1.** Deserialize content of the file to list. `LoadCoins()` **2.** Add item to list. `SaveCoin(Coin coin)` **3.** Serialize list to file. `SaveSettings()` And all these operations you can do in the same file

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correct you just need to change this row:

```
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

to this one:

```
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false);
```

your problem is that you always add to the file new json with all the list instead of just writing the list.

Because you work with file you need and you want to append your only option is to read the file then add elements and write it again.

You can read it when application start and menage it like it seems you do becouse your list is global.

Or you can read it right before you want to write the file.

In any one of this cases you need to add the fix I wrote.

You can use this for read the json o your list:

```
string myJsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);
coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(myJsonString);
```

here is full function:

```
public bool AddACoin (int ID, String coinName, String coinNation, String coinStatus, int coinYear, int quantity, float value)
{
    var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false))
    using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        string myJsonString = File.ReadAllText(path);
        coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(myJsonString);
        coins.Add(new Coin(ID, coinName, coinNation, coinStatus, coinYear, quantity, value));
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, coins.ToList());
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Changing the line you suggest makes the program erase all the content of the JSON. It acts like File.WriteAllText(). Speaking about reading the file, I'm already using what you wrote in its method

Comment: as i wrote this save the list as json as you required there is no option to add JSON object to your array in the file this is why you get more arrays ([] those signs means array). this is why i wrote that you need to read the file first. i added full function